# PyTorch GPU memory management

Tags: pytorch

In my code, I want to replace values in the tensor given values of some indices are zero, for example

```py
target_mac_out[avail_actions[:, 1:] == 0] = -9999999
```

But, it returns OOM

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 166.00 MiB (GPU 0; 10.76 GiB total capacity; 9.45 GiB already allocated; 4.75 MiB free; 9.71 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I think there is no memory allocation because it just visits the tensor of `target_mac_out` and check the value and replace a new value for some indices.

Am I understanding right?

Comment: Are your tensors requiring grad?

Comment: @Ivan `target_mac_out` requires grad while `avail_actions` not.

Comment: can you display a code sample that shows how these tensors were created and initialized ?

Comment: @trialNerror the code is complex, `avail_actions` is a tensor in the GPU and `target_mac_out` is a tensor returned from the network.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess since we do not even know the sizes if the involved tensors, but your indexing `avail_actions[:, 1:] == 0` creates a temporary tensor that does require memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

The `avail_actions[:, 1:] == 0` create a new tensor, and possibly the whole line itself create another tensor before delete the old one after finish the operation.

If speed is not a problem then you can just use `for` loop. Like

```
for i in range(target_mac_out.size(0)):
    for j in range(target_mac_out.size(1)-1):
        if target_mac_out[i, j+1] == 0:
            target_mac_out[i, j+1] = -9999999
```